# Shingled magnetic recording(SMR) device managed - sequential write performance optimizations

Tags: hard-drive, performance-tuning

recently (2020-05) many HDD producers were caught silently replacing CMR lines with SMR disks, which brought more exposure to the whole concept.

It seems that most device-managed SMR disks first write the information on a dedicated area, and then do background updates that hide the write amplification problems. In case I am writing to a an empty disk and  copying large media files which is essentially sequential write , will the SMR device-management firmware be intelligent enough to write directly to the shingled zone instead of storing it in a temporary location and then moving it to the final place?

Is there a way I can optimize the write patterns?

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Earlier today I've come here with the same question, and although I do not have a generic answer, I have a fresh experience.

I've attached an ST1000LM048 externally to a PC, using a decent USB3/SATA converter box with UAS capability. The disk drive is your contemporary bread-and-butter legacy spinning rust notebook drive, with SMR. I actually have another piece of that same drive model inside the PC on SATA. The two drives were purchased some 3 years apart, and both report FW rev. 0001 in smartctl. No update available from Seagate for those drives. My OS is Linux, Debian 11 - which allows me to see under the hood a little, and has some peculiarities in the block and FS layer (NTFS-3G with FUSE 2.9.9).
So much for the overall setup and circumstances.

Today in the morning, I started with a plan to "phase in" the external drive as a portable backup/transport box with USB attachment. I created a partition with NTFS, and on the PC I had a directory structure with several years worth of photoes and some video footage. All of them relatively large files, about 2 MB and up. Slightly over 50 GB total. I just selected a handful of top-level directories and started a copy in the "file explorer" (XFCE Thunar). The initial transfer rate was about 30 MBps (the PC only has USB 2.0). After about 15 GB, the transfer rate started declining, and after 25 GB, it was about 2 MBps, at which point I gracefully paused and canceled the copy - so that the files already copied remained at the destination location, and all the buffers got correctly "synced" to the platters. And, I started probing, exactly where the gremlins could be hiding.

Thunar shows progress and a short-term average transfer rate. I also had "iostat 2" running, and I kept an eye on "Dirty" and "Writeback" in /proc/meminfo. I have dirty_ratio and dirty_background_ratio cranked up to about 80%, and I tried increasing nr_requests in the IO scheduler (mq_deadline) to about 1000. Plus I have the writeback patience extended - to leverage the RAM (paging) as a huge writeback buffer, if possible. Which probably gets hampered by barrier operations... No matter what I tried, writeback never grew above approx 3 MB, while the Dirty could climb well above 1 GB.

I knew in advance (from own past experience) that ntfs-3g in default setup has a characteristic tendency to eat gradually more CPU and back down with the throughput, if you shove some sustained load down the NTFS data path.
So the first thing I tried, I unmounted the drive and unplugged+replugged the USB cable, to flush any ntfs-3g in-memory buffers for that device.
As that didn't bring improvement, I restarted the PC - which in my previous experience did bring relief. Not today though - no signs of improvement. Sluggish transfers practically right after I resumed copying.

Today [I learned, that this quirk in ntfs-3g can be greatly alleviated](https://superuser.com/questions/613869/ntfs-write-speed-really-slow-15mb-s-on-ubuntu) by using two additional mount options: big_writes and lazytime.
Which in my today's particular case, did not help much. I did notice a decrease in CPU usage from 10% to about 1% (consumed by mount.ntfs-3g), so the mount options did work, but still a newly started transfer (to follow up on what got copied previously) ground almost to a halt nearly immediately after another 1 GB or so, we were down to about 2 to 5 MBps.

I also checked if perhaps the disk drive in the sealed external enclosure was running too hot. Not the case, it didn't get above 40*C or so. At the same time, the internal drive was at about 52-55*C and perfectly happy.

So my last guess was: the shingles. Shingled recording. If I stopped the data copy and unmounted the partition, the disk activity LED obediently got dark, but I could hear (and feel in my hand) that the drive kept rattling its head. Clearly it was "janitoring", weaving data from the CMR buffer zone into the shingled tracks. It kept thrashing the head for five more minutes, so I left it running for an hour and in the meantime I went to buy some groceries.
When I got back, the drive was spinning but silent = no seeking activity. So I resumed my copy traffic and... after about 3-5 GB written, I was back to about 5 MBps.

So I gave it some more idle time for janitoring, and then I just resumed copying and let it crawl until the very end of my photo archive.

My conclusion is: the CMR (PMR?) buffer zone is only ever empty in factory pristine state. Once you start writing some data, the CMR buffer is kept filled to some percentage, which is a tradeoff between capacity to take sustained writes vs. optimality of janitoring to the SMR tracks. The disk drive does not try to process all the data from the CMR buffer. Rather, I'd figure that the disk speculates that keeping recently written blocks around is handy, as it likely will be mergeable with more writes at nearby LBA offsets. Thus, if I'm not mistaken, the buffer zone will never again take that initial sustained 10-15 GB worth of writes at a sustained peak CMR transfer rate. (It's vaguely like operating a large river dam. To maximize hydro-electric power generation, the authorities like to keep the level high = run the dam almost full, which hampers the dam's capacity to accomodate flooding events.)

The behavior described here could be characteristic to the particular cheapskate basic notebook disk drive. SMR drives tuned for other purposes (especially NAS / RAID / enterprise use) will likely have more advanced algorithms, more refined tuning.

Also, depending on how the "cached" data is stored in the CMR buffer zone, the fact that ntfs-3g initially filled the CMR buffer with unnecessarily small transactions, might have its own adverse effect on the outside behavior. Perhaps if I started with big_writes and lazytime at the factory-clean startup, the drive would've coped better. Or perhaps not...
I mean to say that I suspect, that my particular OS+FS setup is not the scenario that the disk drive was optimized and tested for.

There don't seem to be any configurable "knobs" to the shingle-janitoring algorithms in the disk drive firmware.
It would be very neat if at least there was a SMART attribute or something, to tell me the current "fill level" of the CMR buffer zone, and I could imagine additional useful efficiency stats on how the janitoring algorithm is faring... but that would probably be asking too much. The flash SSD's don't provide such data either. It's probably too closely related to the proprietary "intellectual property" of the disk drive vendor.

The only way to optimize the traffic, might be by tweaking the FS for larger "cluster size" (allocation unit size), and by tweaking your user-space software that does the writing to issue/commit the writes in big chunks. Which in my experience tends not to be a user-configurable property, even in software where this would help a lot. Such as a web server taking many slow simultaneous uploads from remote users (having to store multiple slow streams into a drive with a limited IOps capability) etc.